# HDFS + how to disable the "du -sk" verifcation on data node disks

Tags: redhat, hdfs

We are using HDP cluster with *182* `data node` machines:

*HDP version - 2.6.4
Ambari version 2.6.1*

We note the following behavior on the `data nodes` machines (its happens on all `data-node` machines and on all disks).

When we perform the command as above example:

```
ps -eo s,user,cmd | grep ^[RD]
D hdfs     du -sk /grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data/current/BP-1018134753-10.3.6.170-1530088122990
D hdfs     du -sk /grid/sdm/hadoop/hdfs/data/current/BP-1018134753-10.3.6.170-1530088122990
R root     ps -eo s,user,cmd
```

Note - each disk in the `data node` is `5.4 T Bytes`.

We can see that `HDFS` is running the "du -sk" on the `data node` disks

We don't like this, because the meaning of that is consuming high load CPU Avrg and sometimes even bad performance.

We are understand that `HDFS` need to run the "`du -sk`" in order to verify the disks space, **but** on other hand its cost - high CPU load avrg and sometimes even poor performance.

Is it possible to tell `HDFS` in some way to disable this verification?